Why return false and not simply return is giving the expected behaviour?
My goal is to limit the length of an input of type number to just one number. For this I used the response of Vikasdeep Singh in this SO answer which in my case is working perfectly. I also had to remove the input inner arrows as I use an onkeypress eventlistener to limit the length of the input. My question is why as shown below when using just return it is not stopping the length of the number while it is when using return false?


input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  appearance: textfield;
}
<input type="number" onkeypress="if(this.value.length===1){return false}">    
<input type="number" onkeypress="if(this.value.length===1){return}">    




return; and return true; works the same. Anything but false will call the default behavior.

Yes but even in MDN return I can't find this subtile difference and it is said that return stops a function as I was usualy use it

It stops the function, yes. But not the event, remember you can have many eventhandlers for the same event (and the same element).
